# Cannot install R package mnormt

Tags: r

I am trying to install the package mnormt but get the following error:

```
> install.packages("mnormt") 
> Installing package into
> ‘C:/Users/dalupus/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’ (as ‘lib’ is
> unspecified) trying URL
> 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/mnormt_1.5-2.zip'
> Warning in install.packages :   cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not
> Found' Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...)
> :    cannot open URL
> 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/mnormt_1.5-2.zip'
> Warning in install.packages :   download of package ‘mnormt’ failed
```

Looking at cran I see that the current version is 1.5-3 but am not sure how to tell that to R and why r thinks the current version is 1.5-2

I tried install.packages("http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/mnormt_1.5-3.zip") but it didn't work.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. You need to give more information.

Comment: This is using R 3.2 on Windows 7.   What I am unclear about is how R decides what version to install and how to tell it to simply grab the 1.5-3 version since I know it is there.

Comment: And now it works.   Must have been a simple hiccup in CRAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I solved this by simply restarting R.  I guess R grabs a new package list with each session.